# QSTK's eventprofiler function doesn't plot properly

Tags: python, pandas, graph, plot, qstk

Using QSTK for Georgia Tech's Coursera Computational Investing course, the eventprofiler function at the end of Examples/EventProfiler/tutorial.py doesn't output the graph shown in the videos. (See image below.)

The other PDFs produced for the exercises for Week 4 are identically empty except for the event numbers, which are correct. Creating PDFs seems like a waste since those numbers could've just been output to terminal.

I looked into the error output for index.py:2204 shown on the image but the fix is not obvious. (Some other backtraces on similar (but not identical) issues on pandas-related github bugs put index.py in the middle of a healthy call stack.)

[image: no graph on plot!]

I might dig deeper into the eventprofiler code if I have time, but I thought I'd ask first. Stack Overflow has almost nothing on QSTK and nothing on pandas that seemed obviously relevant in a quick 5 minute search.

Note: I installed a VirtualBox, Ubuntu and QSTK as instructed in the quantsoftware wiki for the Georgia Tech Coursera Computational Investing course. I've successfully completed all assignments so far, so I think my set up should be OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in EventProfiler.
Which for Ubuntu is installed by default in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/QSTK-0.2.8-py2.7.egg/QSTK/qstkstudy/EventProfiler.py

In this block of code :

```
if b_market_neutral == True:
    df_rets = df_rets - df_rets[s_market_sym]
    del df_rets[s_market_sym]
    del df_events[s_market_sym]
```

The problem is in the substraction. `df_rets` ends up filled with NaNs. Not sure why, something must have changed in the underlying system causing that.
It can be fixed by making the substraction for each symbol in a for loop like this :

```
if b_market_neutral == True:
    for sym in df_events.columns:
        df_rets[sym] = df_rets[sym] - df_rets[s_market_sym]
    del df_rets[s_market_sym]
    del df_events[s_market_sym]
```

You may download an EventProfiler.py file with the fix from [here](https://github.com/LuthienCeleste/ComputationalInvesting/blob/master/EventProfiler.py). Rename the original one in your installation and replace it for this one.
Following a suggestion from Endeavor, who is also in the course you mention, I have also changed the alpha of error bars from 0.1 to 0.6 to make them more visible :

```
if b_errorbars == True:
    plt.errorbar(li_time[i_lookback:], na_mean[i_lookback:],
                yerr=na_std[i_lookback:], ecolor='#AAAAFF',
                alpha=0.6) #Changed alpha from 0.1 to 0.6 (Jose A Dura)
```

Answer (score 0):

i can confirm that the issue is here within the qstkstudy/EventProfiler.py

```
if b_market_neutral == True:
    df_rets = df_rets - df_rets[s_market_sym] # it fails here
    del df_rets[s_market_sym]
    del df_events[s_market_sym]
```

i solved it like this:

```
if b_market_neutral == True:
        df_rets = df_rets.sub(df_rets[s_market_sym].values, axis=0)
        del df_rets[s_market_sym]
        del df_events[s_market_sym]
```