# QSTK EventProfiler runtime error

Tags: python, computational-finance, qstk

When I ran **`QSTK`** EventProfiler tutorial, I have the following warning and I cannot even got the `myEventStudy.pdf` chart.
The code was just stuck there. Having difficulty ruling out the problem. Can anyone please help figure out what is the issue here? Thanks

> `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/QSTK-0.2.8-py2.7.egg/QSTK/qstkutil/qsdateutil.py:36: FutureWarning: TimeSeries is deprecated.` **`Please use Series`**

```
return pd.TimeSeries( index = dates, data = dates )
```

Similar issues can be found via the following link [QSTK's eventprofiler function doesn't plot properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851603/qstks-eventprofiler-function-doesnt-plot-properly)

Answer (score 1):

I modified the return to use Series instead of TimeSeries:

```
return pd.Series(index=dates, data=dates)
```

I don't think it's particularly wise to update the code there, as it will probably get overwritten when it updates. But at that time, hopefully it will be fixed.